# Getting a list of block storage volumes at Rackspace using novaclient Python API

Tags: python, openstack, rackspace, novaclient

I'm trying to get a list of the block storage volumes that I have on my Rackspace account using the novaclient Python API.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
from rackspace_auth_openstack.plugin import RackspaceAuthPlugin from rackspace_auth_openstack.plugin import auth_url_us

from novaclient.client import Client nova = Client(version = 2,
              username = '******',
              project_id = '******',
              api_key = '******************************',
              region_name = 'DFW',
              auth_system = 'rackspace',
              auth_plugin = RackspaceAuthPlugin(),
              auth_url = auth_url_us())

print nova.servers.list() print nova.volumes.list()
```

All of the libraries were installed using `pip install --upgrade rackspace-novaclient` so I should be using the lastest version of the libraries.  Here's the results of running the above code:

```
$ python test.py 
[<Server: svr01>, <Server: svr02>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print nova.volumes.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/v1_1/volumes.py", line 95, in list
    return self._list("/volumes/detail%s" % query_string, "volumes")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/base.py", line 64, in _list
    _resp, body = self.api.client.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 283, in get
    return self._cs_request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 260, in _cs_request
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 242, in _time_request
    resp, body = self.request(url, method, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 236, in request
    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body, url, method)
novaclient.exceptions.NotFound: Not found (HTTP 404)
```

The server list API call works, so I'm pretty sure that I'm authenticating properly.  The CLI command `nova volume-list` works properly so it would appear that I'm missing something from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Cloud Block Storage API is under a different endpoint, you have to specify the service_type

```
from rackspace_auth_openstack.plugin import RackspaceAuthPlugin, auth_url_us

from novaclient.client import Client
nova = Client(version = 2,
              username = '******',
              project_id = '******',
              api_key = '******************************',
              region_name = 'DFW',
              auth_system = 'rackspace',
              auth_plugin = RackspaceAuthPlugin(),
              auth_url = auth_url_us(),
              service_type = 'volume') # Right here

print nova.volumes.list()
```

Comment: This gets me the information I'm looking for. However is there no way to do this with a single Client object or is this because of the way Rackspace has structured their services?

Comment: The client object keeps an endpoint stored internally. You could theoretically perform this with a single client, but it would involve manually updating the endpoint or re-authenticating every time. Nova-client was originally written with the idea that it would be used only for Nova, but the structure failed to adapt once we added support for services that interact with Nova.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and confirmed that novaclient behaves differently when using its CLI and when using its Python module. I've forwarded this issue to the team in Rackspace that works on novaclient; I hope that one of them will be able to shed more light on this.